# flutter ui.Image memory

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, memory

```
void setPixelColor(List<Offset> points, double brushSize, Color color) { 
        ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder(); 
    ui.Canvas canvas = ui.Canvas(recorder); canvas.drawImage(layers[currentEditLayout].uiImage!, Offset.zero, Paint());
    canvas.drawPoints(
        ui.PointMode.points,
        points,
        Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..strokeWidth = 1);


    ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    
    layers[currentEditLayout].uiImage!.dispose();
    layers[currentEditLayout].uiImage = null;
    
    layers[currentEditLayout].uiImage = picture.toImageSync(canvasSize.width.toInt(),canvasSize.height.toInt());
    picture.dispose();
}
```

I tried to run this function inside a for loop, but the memory was growing badly. I expect stable running memory